# Having trouble deleting old DHCP configuration from interface

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I switched my router and my new one is setup with different IP ranges for the dhcp clients. Old one was 192.168.0.0/24, new one 192.168.88.0/24. My ubuntu server that is in my network won't loose that old configuration for some reason, the welcome message already shows both IPs bound for the enp3s0 interface.

```
IPv4 address for enp3s0:          192.168.88.248
IPv4 address for enp3s0:          192.168.0.101
```

ip a output:

```
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:1d:ef:22:7a:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.88.248/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 389sec preferred_lft 389sec
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2b75:b1cd:3e2f:ca2b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6a1d:efff:fe22:7a40/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ifconfig interestingly only shows the new config:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.248  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::2b75:b1cd:3e2f:ca2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::6a1d:efff:fe22:7a40  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:1d:ef:22:7a:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 266491  bytes 258276943 (258.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 137081  bytes 11888532 (11.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route -n also shows the old route that I want to delete:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp3s0
```

This also includes the old DNS server that I configured (8.8.8.8), it always comes back in the file /etc/resolv.conf

What I tried:

- adjusted my netplan and applied new netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.88.1, 1.1.1.1]
```

- flushed all IPs for enp3s0
- deleted the bound IP via "ip addr del", but it gets reset after reboot
- /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases only has the new leases

Question:

How can I find out which program resets my IP config and DNS?

Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-75-generic x86_64)

Comment: Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-75-generic x86_64), no desktop has been added. Changed renderer to networkd now

Comment: How did you configure it *before* networkd was your renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

At the bottom was a static IP entered that was re-applied after every reboot. This entry was not deleted by applying the netplan. I have now commented it out.

```
#interface enp3s0
#        static ip_address=192.168.0.101/24
#        static routers=192.168.0.1
#        static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```